# What directive to use for NG animate

Tags: angularjs

I am trying use ng-animate so far without success. I animate different part of my program and everything is working fine. But in this part I don't know what directive I shout use. I tried #singleQuestionAnswer.ng-enter .. ng-leave but didn't work.

```
<div class="row" id="singleQuestionAnswer">
<div class="column" >
    <h3>$ctrl.quizQuestions[$ctrl.activeQuestion].question}}</h3>
    <div class="row">
        <div layout="column"  ng-repeat="answer in $ctrl.answers">
            <div class="answer" layout-padding>
                <md-checkbox ng-checked="$ctrl.existAnswer(answer, $ctrl.answersSelected)" >
                    {{answer}}
                </md-checkbox>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<md-button ng-click="$ctrl.answered($ctrl.active)" >Submit answer</md-button>
```

Comment: Provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The [ng-if directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) supports the [enter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$animate#enter) and [leave](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$animate#leave) effects.

Comment: Thank you. How can I use them in my scenario?

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).